# Removed post caused minus 2 points

Tags: support, reputation

My first question on Meta.

Today I noticed I got 2 reputations minus for a post which got removed. I hardly remember what I did to that post, in the history of reps achieved I couldn't find it for either an edit or any up vote. May be I have voted the question which I don't remember.

Let me know how this is maintained, so that I can be careful next time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You edited [the post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139547/builddirectory-environment-variable-name-in-tfs-2013-is-not-working) on April 24, and once it got approved you earned 2 reputation points. Now this post have been deleted and all reputations earned on that post will also be deleted. Note that this happens on deleted posts only, and not closed questions.

Comment: Hi Benny, Thanks for answer it clears my doubt. :)